# Ubuntu: How to use Debian DVD images (iso) as Repository?

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, repository

i use Ubuntu. i have 5 **Debian DVDs** as iso files. how could i introduce them to Ubuntu as **repository**?

i do not want to burn them and waste a DVD. i just want to mount them and use `apt-cdrom` .
any one have experience?

Answer (score 1):

Mixing packages from different distributions usually doesn't work or causes all sorts of problems. To do it you need some good understanding of the package management as you'll have to fight against package dependencies. And most likely a lot of programs will not work.

**Don't do it.**

If you still want to try it:

Add something like

```
/you/path/debian-XXX.iso /mnt iso9660 loop,defaults 0 0
```

to your /etc/fstab and use

```
sudo apt-cdrom  -d /mnt add
```

to add it.

Comment: thanks, i will test it. and about your advice, i think you are wrong with ubuntu and debian. i have used debian CDs for ubuntu before and there were no problem. ubuntu is debian-based and debian .deb files should run on ubuntu well, am i wrong?

Comment: Different distros (and even different versions of the same distro) use different package names for the same libraries, and may have different versions of standard libraries (e.g. glibc).  It's possible to create a .deb containing just scripts or static binaries so that it will still work on pretty much any .deb distro, but most packages included with a distro depend on some library packages from their distro, so you'll have difficulty installing and running them on a different distro.